# What is system-centered design?

Tags: design, user-centered-design, hci, system

I can't understand the idea or concept of system-centered design. I have researched the topic but it mostly directs me to user-centered design.

What is system-centered design?

Answer (score 3):

[Difference between System vs User Centered Design](https://hci.cs.siue.edu/NSF/Files/Semester/Week1-2/PPT-Text/Slide8.html)

System Centered Design seems to refer to the design of a system's backbone architecture, database, etc. Prioritizing the efficiency of the system rather than the user.

[Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_design)

> Systems design is the process of defining the architecture, modules, interfaces, and data for a system to satisfy specified requirements. Systems design could be seen as the application of systems theory to product development. There is some overlap with the disciplines of systems analysis, systems architecture and systems engineering.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_design)

Answer (score 1):

It is often hard to say what these terms mean without understanding the context within which it is actually used. However, there are a number of concepts closely related to some interpretations of 'system centred design' that relate to trying to expand the scope of analysis when it comes to either the business, technical and user requirements beyond the immediate application (i.e. product or service).

A popular term often used for this is to design an 'ecosystem', where you are looking at the relationships between all the products and services, but not from a typical service design perspective where it is about both the visible and invisible (as least to the user) aspects of the product or service, but how the different products and services relate to each other in delivering a holistic user experience.